# Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, certificate

I have WCF service that is setup to use server and client certificate like this :

```
     ServiceHostFactory.CreateService<MyAppClientService>($"https://localhost:{serverSettings.SmartCardSSLPort}/MyApp5Service/Sll")
                        .UseProtobuf()
                        .AddServiceBehavior(new CustomServiceBehavior_ClientService())
                        .AddAuthorizationPolicy(new CustomAuthorizationPolicy_ClientService())
                        .UseSecureConnection(environmentSettings.SecureConnection)
                        .UseThrottling()
                        .Start(EndpointService.CreateNetHttpsBinding(true));
                    await ServiceHandler.RegisterClientServiceToConsul(MyAppServices.ClientServer_Smartcard, serverSettings.SmartCardSSLPort);

public ServiceHostBuilder<T> UseSecureConnection(SecureConnectionSettings settings)
        {
            if (settings != null && settings.Enabled)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Setting certificates");
                X509Store store = new X509Store(settings.CertificateStore, settings.CertificateLocation);
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                X509Certificate2Collection certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, settings.Thumbprint, true);
                store.Close();

                if (certs.Count > 0)
                {
                    _serviceHost.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(settings.CertificateLocation,
                    settings.CertificateStore, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, settings.Thumbprint);
                }
                else
                    throw new Exception("Could not find certificate with thumbprint " + settings.Thumbprint);
            }
            return this;
        }

public static NetHttpsBinding CreateNetHttpsBinding(bool requiredClientCertificate = false)
        {
            var binding = new NetHttpsBinding();
            SetBindingSettings(binding);
            binding.Security = new BasicHttpsSecurity();
            binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport;
            binding.Security.Transport = new HttpTransportSecurity();

            if (requiredClientCertificate)
                binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
            else
                binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;

            return binding;
        }
```

The client creates the channel like this :

```
private async Task<ChannelFactory<T>> CreateChannelFactory(LoginTypeBase loginType, OrbitToken token)
        {
            var service = await _ConsulService.GetServiceBlocking(loginType.OrbitServicesToUse, forceRefresh: true, token: new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)).Token);

            if (service == null)
                throw new OrbitServiceCommunicationException();

            var cert = loginType.ClientCertificate;
            var uri = loginType.GetOrbitClientServiceURL(service.Address, service.Port);

            var header = AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader(nameof(OrbitToken), nameof(OrbitToken), token);
            var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(uri, header);

            ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint = null;
            if (loginType.LoginType == LoginType.SmartCard || loginType.LoginType == LoginType.UsernamePasswordSLL)
            {
                var binding = new NetHttpsBinding("netHttpsBinding");
                binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport;
                if (loginType.LoginType == LoginType.SmartCard)
                    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
                else
                    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;

                serviceEndpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(T)), binding, endpointAddress);
            }
            else
            {
                var binding = new NetHttpBinding("netHttpBinding");
                serviceEndpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(T)), binding, endpointAddress);
            }

            serviceEndpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new ProtoEndpointBehavior());
            serviceEndpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new CustomMessageInspectorBehavior());


            var v = new ChannelFactory<T>(serviceEndpoint);
            if (loginType.LoginType == LoginType.SmartCard)
            {
                v.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = cert;
                //v.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, cert.Thumbprint);
            }
            return v;
        }
```

When a smartcard is inserted into the reader the thirdparty program will copy the certificates from this card in to the local store.

My application will catch this change and use one of these certificate as client certificate.

The above code works fine the first time. When the client makes the first call to the service the thirdpary program will ask a pin of the user and if this is valid then the communication continues.

The problem is if I remove the smartcard and then put it back in I will get a  SSL/TLS when the next call to the service is done? I have at this point not created a new channel but uese the same channel as before I removed the card.

Is there something going on here in .NET or is it my thirdparty software that blocks me? Maybe I have to create a new channel after a certificate have ben removed and then put in again?

This is an example of the exception I get :

> System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: Could not
>   establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority
>   '139.107.245.141:44310'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was
>   aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   result)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   MyApp.Client.Main.Classes.Controllers.ErrorHandler.UnwrapAgentException(Exception
>   exception) in C:\MyApp\Produkter\MyApp
>   Utveckling\Solution\MyApp.Client.Main\Classes\Controllers\ErrorHandler.cs:line
>   35    at
>   MyApp.Client.Main.ServiceManagement.ServiceAgents.AkutlistanAgent.GetAkutListan(List`1
>   orgEnhetList, List`1 tooltipKeys, List`1 userItems) in
>   C:\Myapp\Produkter\Myapp
>   Utveckling\Solution\Myapp.Client.Main\Classes\Service
>   Management\Service Agents\AkutlistanAgent.cs:line 88    at
>   Myapp.Client.Main.GUI.Akutlista.ucAkutLista.buildGrid() in
>   C:\Myapp\Produkter\Myapp
>   Utveckling\Solution\Myapp.Client.Main\GUI\Akutlista\ucAkutLista.cs:line
>   550    at
>   Myapp.Client.Main.GUI.Akutlista.ucAkutLista.SetArbetsstalle(List`1
>   orgEnhetList) in C:\Myapp\Produkter\Myapp
>   Utveckling\Solution\Myapp.Client.Main\GUI\Akutlista\ucAkutLista.cs:line
>   1742    at
>   Myapp.Client.Main.GUI.Akutlista.ucAkutLista.OrgEnhetList_EditValueChanged(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Myapp\Produkter\Myapp
>   Utveckling\Solution\Myapp.Client.Main\GUI\Akutlista\ucAkutLista.cs:line
>   1828    at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>
>   at
>   DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItem.RaiseEditValueChangedCore(EventArgs
>   e)    at
>   DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItem.RaiseEditValueChanged(EventArgs
>   e)    at DevExpress.XtraEditors.BaseEdit.RaiseEditValueChanged()    at
>   DevExpress.XtraEditors.BaseEdit.OnEditValueChanged()    at
>   DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextEdit.OnEditValueChanged()    at
>   DevExpress.XtraEditors.BaseEdit.OnEditValueChanging(ChangingEventArgs
>   e)    at
>   DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextEdit.OnEditValueChanging(ChangingEventArgs
>   e)    at DevExpress.XtraEditors.BaseEdit.set_EditValue(Object value)
>
>   at
>   Myapp.Client.Main.GUI.Akutlista.ucAkutLista.SetActiveOrganisationEnhet(List`1
>   organisationsEnhetList, List`1 prioriteringsGruppList) in
>   C:\Myapp\Produkter\Myapp
>   Utveckling\Solution\Myapp.Client.Main\GUI\Akutlista\ucAkutLista.cs:line
>   1731    at Myapp.Client.Main.GUI.Akutlista.ucAkutLista.LoadControl()
>   in C:\Myapp\Produkter\Myapp
>   Utveckling\Solution\Myapp.Client.Main\GUI\Akutlista\ucAkutLista.cs:line
>   395    at
>   Myapp.Client.Main.GUI.Planering.ucOversiktsTabControl.loadPage() in
>   C:\Myapp\Produkter\Myapp
>   Utveckling\Solution\Myapp.Client.Main\GUI\Planering\ucOversiktsTabControl.cs:line
>   703    at
>   Myapp.Client.Main.GUI.Planering.ucOversiktsTabControl..ctor() in
>   C:\Myapp\Produkter\Myapp
>   Utveckling\Solution\Myapp.Client.Main\GUI\Planering\ucOversiktsTabControl.cs:line
>   68    at
>   Myapp.Client.Main.GUI.Planering.frmPlaneringsOversikt.InitializeComponent()
>   in C:\Myapp\Produkter\Myapp
>   Utveckling\Solution\Myapp.Client.Main\GUI\Planering\frmPlaneringsOversikt.Designer.cs:line
>   180    at
>   Myapp.Client.Main.GUI.Planering.frmPlaneringsOversikt..ctor() in
>   C:\Myapp\Produkter\Myapp
>   Utveckling\Solution\Myapp.Client.Main\GUI\Planering\frmPlaneringsOversikt.cs:line
>   147    at
>   Myapp.Client.Main.GUI.Planering.frmPlaneringsOversikt.OpenForm() in
>   C:\Myapp\Produkter\Myapp
>   Utveckling\Solution\Myapp.Client.Main\GUI\Planering\frmPlaneringsOversikt.cs:line
>   112    at Myapp.Client.Main.GUI.frmMainMyapp.OpenPlaningOverview() in
>   C:\Myapp\Produkter\Myapp
>   Utveckling\Solution\Myapp.Client.Main\GUI\frmMainMyapp.cs:line 2265
>   at
>   Myapp.Client.Main.GUI.frmMainMyapp.navBarItemPlanering_LinkClicked(Object
>   sender, NavBarLinkEventArgs e) in C:\Myapp\Produkter\Myapp
>   Utveckling\Solution\Myapp.Client.Main\GUI\frmMainMyapp.cs:line 619
>   at DevExpress.XtraNavBar.NavBarItem.RaiseLinkEvent(Object linkEvent,
>   NavBarItemLink link)    at
>   DevExpress.XtraNavBar.NavBarItem.RaiseLinkClicked(NavBarItemLink link)
>   at
>   DevExpress.XtraNavBar.NavBarItem.RaiseLinkClickedCore(NavBarItemLink
>   link)    at
>   DevExpress.XtraNavBar.NavBarControl.RaiseLinkClicked(NavBarItemLink
>   link)    at
>   DevExpress.XtraNavBar.ViewInfo.NavBarViewInfo.DoLinkClick(NavBarHitInfo
>   hitInfo)    at
>   DevExpress.XtraNavBar.ViewInfo.NavBarViewInfo.DoClick(NavBarHitInfo
>   hitInfo)    at
>   DevExpress.XtraNavBar.ViewInfo.NavigationPaneViewInfo.DoClick(NavBarHitInfo
>   hitInfo)    at
>   DevExpress.XtraNavBar.ViewInfo.NavBarViewInfo.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs
>   e)    at DevExpress.XtraNavBar.NavBarControl.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs
>   ev)    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m,
>   MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   DevExpress.XtraNavBar.NavBarControl.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Edit : I have a tips about MS WinInet might be the problem, to overcome it I need to restart the application or in some way reset MS WinInet?

Comment: Might this be becouse of MS WinInet?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your firewall settings? If so then it's worth checking the right port is being opened for communications.

Comment: This is more an comment than an answer. Please consider to delete it and add it as comment. Or add more valuable content to it.

Comment: As it workes the first time it should also work after the card is removed and then replaced. Its the same port that is used all the time.